# What's the easiest way to configure GRUB in a more user friendly way?

Tags: grub2

Here is something I'd like for it to do that it does not do by default, and which seem to require (somehow) a bit of research to configure.

What I want is simple. Select the OS that I chose the last time.

Note: I am running 11.10 now which I believe is GRUB 2 but I don't know what version (1.99?)

Comment: check the grub version using `grub-install -v` command in terminal.

Comment: And, I have two solutions, but none of them would choose the OS which **selected last time**. **1st one** would help to select which OS should be boot-up on **next start-up** and **2nd one** just to set another OS as **default to boot-up** on every start-up. Do you want them?

Comment: I think I've figured out how to set the default (set an index for the entry in `/etc/default/grub`, run `update-grub` after) but setting for the next startup would be useful.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. [grub-choose-default](http://digamma.cs.unm.edu/trac.dmohr/wiki/GrubChooseDefault) may help you to choose OS for next start-up before shutting down the current one. :)

Answer (score 2):

### Last selected entry

To configure grub2 to remember the last selected entry, put these parameters in `/etc/default/grub` :

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

and save this configuration using the command :

```
update-grub
```

### Specific entry

If you want to select a specific entry and don't want it to change if a new kernel is installed, you have to use the name of this entry instead of its index number. You took the name in the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` :

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 3.2.0-30-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    savedefault
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35b16ba3-50a4-4832-bd60-644db6670637
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-30-generic root=UUID=35b16ba3-50a4-4832-bd60-644db6670637 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-30-generic
}
```

And use it in the file `/etc/default/grub` :

```
GRUB_DEFAULT='Ubuntu, avec Linux 3.2.0-30-generic'
```

Save configuration with :

```
update-grub
```

Answer (score 1):

For me , the quickest, safest, easiest way is getting **grub-customizer** which customizes your Grub.

Giving it a try is an option.

[grub-customizer [image: Install grub-customizer]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/grub-customizer)

[image: Install via the software center]

[grub-customizer [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)