# How can i modify my Grub 1.99 configurations to install a new kernel?

Tags: installation, grub2, kernel, configuration

I have configured kernel 3.2.x and made some changes in the kernel. I have compiled it and have the compiled image of the kernel with me. 
The problem i am facing is as in how to modify the boot loader Grub 1.99 in my case, so that i can boot through the new kernel i have compiled.

I looked on net for any tutorials but all of them talked about older versions of Grub ?

Can someone please give some info or point me towards some resource ?

Currently i have compiled my new custom kernel image and have copied it to `/boot`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to configure GRUB in a more user friendly way?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102742/whats-the-easiest-way-to-configure-grub-in-a-more-user-friendly-way)

Comment: @NikTh I don't think it is. that question is asking about how to modify grub so that it permanently remembers the last kernel choice selected. It is kind of related as in talks about a different way to config the grub but i am asking about as in how to install a new kernel image with grub 1.99

Comment: How you installed the kernel ? didn't you create .deb packages? If you didn't create .deb packages then you should create an initramfs and then update the grub , is not an exclusive matter of grub.

Comment: @NikTh I have still not installed kernel. I have just compiled it and copied the image in /boot/mykernel . Yes this is wanted to know as in how to proceed after this till the end. Can you help me on this.. Thanks

Comment: So you didn't create .deb packages , am I right? Because if you did create , then just install the packages and `update-grub` and should be fine. Or else have a look here: [BodhiZazen.net - tutorials - Kernel compile/install](http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/kernel#lspci). The comments section is not appropriate for such discuss. Good Luck.

Comment: @NikTh Thanks a lot i will have a look  at that

Comment: @NikTh Can your last comment solved my problem. Can you please add that as an answer so that i can accept it.many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you didn't create .deb packages , am I right? Because if you did create , then just install the packages and update-grub and should be fine.

You can update grub with the command below (in terminal)

```
sudo update-grub
```

Or else have a look here: [BodhiZazen.com - tutorials - Kernel compile/install.](http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/kernel#lspci)